# Why showing error when conecting to database using pdo?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I am trying to lean PDO. Here is my sample code.

```
<?php
$dbname     = "procedure_testing";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "mypass";
 $host="localhost";
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname', $dbuser, $dbpass);
$id=3;
 $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM salary WHERE empid = :empid');
$stmt->execute(array('empid' => $id));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ( count($result) ) { 
foreach($result as $row) {
  print_r($row);
}   
} else {
echo "No rows returned.";
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

But i am getting this following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo_example\select.php on line 10

I don't know what is the problem. Please can anyone check my code and help me?

Comment: Also you have single quotes in creating PDO object, then your variable is not parsed correctly. Change it to double quotes or escape the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there you forget `:`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM salary WHERE empid = :empid');
$stmt->execute(array(':empid' => $id)); //notice : in front of empid.
```

Comment: I used : infront of empid according to your answer and also used double quotes. But still facing same problem.